# jquery string an array between '

Tags: jquery, arrays, jqplot

I'm new to jQuery and I have a small problem.
I'm using the jQplot plugin and I have the code:

```
var plotName = ['bearShevaPlot', 'haifaPlot', 'tiberiasPlot', 'kfarSabaPlot', 'netanyaPlot', 'rishonLezionPlot', 'rehovotPlot', 'telAvivPlot'];
var chartName = ['bearShevaCity', 'haifaCity', 'tiberiasCity', 'kfarSabaCity', 'netanyaCity', 'rishonLezionCity', 'rehovotCity', 'telAvivCity'];
$.each(plotName,function(a,b){
        chartName[a];
        //console.log(chartName[a] +', '+ b);
        var b = $.jqplot('/*chartName[a]*/', [haifa], {
          seriesColors: ["#FF2B00"],
          title:'',
          seriesDefaults: {showMarker:false,lineWidth:2,shadow:false},
          grid:{background:'#4C4C4C'},
          axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 12,
                    tickOptions:{
                              formatString:'%.0f'
                        },
                },
         },
       });
});
```

Now where I have the chartName[a] in comment (/*chartName[a]*/) I need to string this array but I don't know how to do it with the ' char (') around it...

Thanks for the help and sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: It's already a string. Both arrays contain nothing but strings. What do you mean you need to "string this array"?

Comment: Hint: don't use variables like `a`, `b`, etc.; use descriptive variable names such as `idx`, `obj` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$.jqplot('/*'+chartName[a]+'*/', ...
```